# How to make .htaccess acccept a var with a point (.)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a porblem with .htaccess.
A made this:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

But when someone have a profile with a point(example: opticross.crime) the site redirect me to 404 error

Comment: Did you try adding it to the regex?

Comment: The problem that I don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Works!.. Thank you

Comment: There is no need to escape the dot. It doesn't have any special meaning in a character class. The only character that needs escaping in a character class is `]`. Even the dash (`-`) can be used unescaped if it is the very first or the very last character from the set.